# Custom keyboard containing scrollview

Tags: android, keyboard, scrollview

I've been trying to create a custom android keyboard. I've started looking over "[Creating an Input Method](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)"  guide from Google and I was able to create a regular keyboard using the Keyboard and KeyboardView elements.

The problem is that my keyboard needs a scrollview (or a recyclerview) so the user can scroll and see more items of the keyboard - but I don't think this can be achieved using the default Keyboard and KeyboardView elements.

I also tried to override the **onCreateInputView** method and  add a custom layout that contained a scrollview - but the height of the keyboard was taking the entire screen and the user couldn't interact with the app anymore.

So if anyone has some ideas on how I can overcome this issues I would love to hear your suggestions.

Thanks